# rails nested attribute do not show in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I added a nested attribute to my form, the fields for the nested attribute which is Education fields do not render, the other fields do. The relationships appear to be in order and the controller does too.

Here is the code.

**Controller**

```
def new
  @profile = current_user.build_student_profile
end

def profile_params
  params.require(:student_profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :gender, student_profiles_attributes: [:degree, :university_id, :major, :major2, :start_date, :end_date, :grade, :grade_scale] )
end
```

**Models**

```
class Education < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student_profile
  belongs_to :university
  validates :grade_scale, inclusion: { in: %w(GPA4 GPA7 WAM100) }
  validates :degree, :university_id, :major, :start_date, :end_date, :grade, :grade_scale, presence: true
end
class StudentProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :educations
  validates :gender, inclusion: { in: %w(male female) }
  validates :first_name, :last_name, :gender, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :educations
end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for (@profile) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= f.label :last_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  <%= f.label :gender %>
  <%= f.text_field :gender %>
  <%= f.fields_for :educations do |education_fields| %>
  <%= education_fields.label :Degree %>
  <%= education_fields.text_field :degree %>
  <%= education_fields.label :University %>
  <%= education_fields.collection_select(:university_id, University.all, :id, :name) %>
  <%= education_fields.label :Major %>
  <%= education_fields.text_field :major %>
  <%= education_fields.label :Additional_Major %>
  <%= education_fields.text_field :major2 %>
  <%= education_fields.label :Start_Date %>
  <%= education_fields.date_field :start_date %>
  <%= education_fields.label :End_Date %>
  <%= education_fields.date_field :end_date %>
  <%= education_fields.label :Grade %>
  <%= education_fields.number_field :grade %>
  <%= education_fields.label :Grade_Scale %>
  <%= education_fields.select :grade_scale, [["GPA / 4","GPA4"], ["GPA / 7","GPA7"], ["WAM / 100","WAM100"]] %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I have tried to add the following to the controller new action `@profile.educations.build` but I get an error unknown attribute student_profile_id

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have `student_profile_id` attribute/column present in `educations` table.

After that, as you have mentioned, you need to build `educations` object on `student_profile` as:

```
def new
  @profile = current_user.build_student_profile
  @profile.educations.build
end
```

Comment: I've tried that, I get `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError student_profile_id`

Comment: Make sure you have `student_profile_id` attribute/column present in educations table.

Comment: Thanks for that, it looks like I put the id in the wrong table

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<%= f.fields_for(:educations,@profile.educations.build) do |education_fields| %>
<% end %>`

or

`def new
  @profile = current_user.build_student_profile
  @educations = @profile.educations.build
end`

`<%= f.fields_for(@educations) do |education_fields| %>
<% end %>`

Comment: I didn't have student_profile_id in the educations table